Google play - Update rejected Families Policy Requirements: Login Credentials
I'm trying to understand what is wrong with the username and the password that I set in the App access, Google claims in the rejection message that "We could not access the in-app content with the login credentials that you have provided". but in our logs, we see that they logged in to our system also I've tried the username that I provided and everything went fine. so what am I missing? Is anyone else experiencing the same problem? Thanks.


Did you manage to solve this? Have the same issue, but i provided proper instructions to them, but they still rejected the app

Hi, in my case it was an error in the password so the solution was quite simple. but even though the password was corrected they rejected my app once again and an appeal had to be filed for the application to be approved.
